# Spring Data support for Redis BRPOPLPUSH

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using Jedis for Accessing Redis via Spring Data.

```
<bean
    id="jedisPoolConfig"
    class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig"
    p:maxTotal="100"
    p:maxIdle="10"
    p:maxWaitMillis="5000"
/> 

<bean id="jedisConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
    p:host-name="${redis.server.host}" p:port="${redis.server.port}"
    p:password="${redis.server.password}" 
    p:use-pool="${redis.server.usepool}" 
    p:pool-config-ref="jedisPoolConfig"/>

<bean id="genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer"/>

<bean id="stringSerializer" class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer"/>       


<!-- redis template definition -->  
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"      p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory">      <property name="keySerializer" ref="stringSerializer"/>
        <property name="hashKeySerializer" ref="stringSerializer"/>
        <property name="hashValueSerializer" ref="genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer"/>
</bean>     

<bean id="stringRedisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.StringRedisTemplate"      p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnectionFactory" />
```

Would like to perform `BRPOPLPUSH`, I dont see this option under

```
   OPTION_1  -> getRedisTemplate().boundListOps("Key").*

   OPTION_2 -> getRedisTemplate().opsForList().rightPopAndLeftPush("sourceKey", "destinationKey")  ---> No blocking ?
```

Instead it is available at,

```
   OPTION_3 -> getRedisTemplate().getConnectionFactory().getConnection().bRPopLPush(timeout, srcKey, dstKey)
```

**Question_0**: Is this the only option? Why it is not available in above two api's?

**Answer_0**: No, whenever timeunit is mentioned with `left/rightPop(timeout, unit)` in `boundListOps`, `opsForList` it is blocking call. timeunit with 0 seconds for blocking for ever.

**Question_1**: Why there are so many variants ..? or May be when to use `boundListOps`, `opsForList` and `getConnection`?

**Partial_Answer_1**: Looks like if multiple operation to be acted upon a single key then boundListOps, because it is bound to that single key, and no need to mention that in the repeated actions, where as in opsForList, every action key has to be mentioned.

From doc of boundListOps:

> Returns the operations performed on list values bound to the given
>   key.

Just note that, boundListOps still uses opsForList inherently by passing the registered key to it.

Ok, still when should i use directly `getConnectionFactory().getConnection()` ?

**Question_2**: If i use `getConnectionFactory().getConnection()`, Do i need to close() this connection under `finally(){}`? (Since this is the one currently having `blocking RPopLPush` support).

From the code `boundListOps` is inherently using opsForList, and its all action are executed with finally like below with release connection, hence asked.

```
RedisTemplate.java
 public <T> T execute(RedisCallback<T> action, boolean exposeConnection, boolean pipeline) {
RedisConnectionFactory factory = getConnectionFactory();
        RedisConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(factory);
            ...
            ...
        // TODO: any other connection processing?
        return postProcessResult(result, connToUse, existingConnection);
        } finally {
            RedisConnectionUtils.releaseConnection(conn, factory);
        }
```

**Question_3**: Why `getRedisTemplate().boundListOps("key").rightPush(new HashMap());` is accepting `Map` instead of value like `String/Object`  though `"key"` is already mentioned...?

**Answer_3**: It is my problem, I have declared that way.

```
public RedisTemplate<String, Map<String, Object>> getRedisTemplate() {
        return redisTemplate;
}
```

And the same RedisTemplate object is passed as this while fetching DefaultBoundListOperations where V is referred from RedisTemplate.

```
public BoundListOperations<K, V> boundListOps(K key) {
    return new DefaultBoundListOperations<K, V>(key, this);
}

class DefaultBoundListOperations<K, V> extends DefaultBoundKeyOperations<K> implements BoundListOperations<K, V> {

    public DefaultBoundListOperations(K key, RedisOperations<K, V> operations) {
        super(key, operations); //RedisOperations<K, V> is converted to BoundListOperations<K, V> here
        this.ops = operations.opsForList();
    }
}
```

**Question_4**: Why `getConnection().bRPopLPush` is accepting `srcKey, dstKey` as `byte[]` instead of `String` ..?

Sorry for many questions, it is all raised because i don't find proper java doc in spring data OR tutorials to explain the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 4: First of all, it's important to note that Redis keys and values [can be any binary](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro). Spring-data templates abstract this away and let developers deal with Java objects rather than byte arrays. See the following quote from the [spring-data reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template):

> ...The template offers a high-level abstraction for Redis interactions. While RedisConnection offers low level methods that accept and return binary values (byte arrays), the template takes care of serialization and connection management, freeing the user from dealing with such details.

It seems that when working with `RedisConnection`, Spring doesn't know what type your key or value is, and it makes no effort to convert an object (e.g., `String`) to the binary Redis understands, hence, you are required to pass the raw binary to Redis.

Answer (score 0):

First, call `RedisTemplate.opsForList()` to get `ListOperations`.
Then, use `ListOperations.rightPopAndLeftPush(K sourceKey, K destinationKey, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` to do BRPOPLPUSH.